# Return Monthly Data From Query Even When Month Does Not Exist In DataSet

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a MS SQL Server guy, but am having to write some MySQL Queries.  I am attempting to write a query that will show monthly sales data for a selected employee and if the employee has no sales data for that month show the month and a 0.

This is the query I have but it's returning NULL?

```
CREATE TABLE `saleamountbyemployee` (
  `month_year` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_sales` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee` char(17) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `saleamountbyemployee` (`month_year`,`total_sales`,`employee`) VALUES ('Feb 18','34512','James Jones'); 

INSERT INTO `saleamountbyemployee` (`month_year`,`total_sales`,`employee`) VALUES ('Feb 18','223','Sally Smith'); 

INSERT INTO `saleamountbyemployee` (`month_year`,`total_sales`,`employee`) VALUES ('Feb 18','22','James Jones'); 

WITH RECURSIVE
cte_months_to_pull AS (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@start_date, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL @number_of_months MONTH AS month_to_pull
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month_to_pull + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    FROM cte_months_to_pull
    WHERE month_to_pull < @start_date + INTERVAL @number_of_months - 2 MONTH
)
SELECT YRS.months_to_pull,T.employee,COALESCE(T.IA, 0) IA
FROM (SELECT DATE_Format(month_to_pull, '%b-%Y') months_to_pull
      FROM cte_months_to_pull
      ORDER BY months_to_pull
     ) AS YRS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Date_format(month_year, '%b-%Y') AS `Month`
                 ,employee,Sum(total_sales) AS IA

           FROM   saleamountbyemployee
           WHERE  employee = 'James Jones'
           GROUP  BY Date_format(month_year, '%b-%Y'), employee) T
ON YRS.months_to_pull = T.`Month`
order by month(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-',months_to_pull), '%d-%b-%Y')),YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-',months_to_pull), '%d-%b-%Y'))
```

**EDIT**
If I alter syntax to this:

```
SET @start_date = 'Jan 18';
SET @number_of_months = 12;

WITH RECURSIVE
cte_months_to_pull AS (
    SELECT str_to_date(CONCAT(@start_date,' 01'), '%b %y %d') - INTERVAL @number_of_months MONTH AS month_to_pull
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month_to_pull + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    FROM cte_months_to_pull
    WHERE month_to_pull < @start_date + INTERVAL @number_of_months - 2 MONTH
)
SELECT YRS.months_to_pull,T.employee,COALESCE(T.IA, 0) IA
FROM (SELECT DATE_Format(month_to_pull, '%b-%Y') months_to_pull
      FROM cte_months_to_pull
      ORDER BY months_to_pull
     ) AS YRS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Date_format(month_year, '%b-%Y') AS `Month`
                 ,employee,Sum(total_sales) AS IA

           FROM   saleamountbyemployee
           WHERE  employee = 'James Jones'
           GROUP  BY Date_format(month_year, '%b-%Y'), employee) T
ON YRS.months_to_pull = T.`Month`
order by month(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-',months_to_pull), '%d-%b-%Y')),YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-',months_to_pull), '%d-%b-%Y'))
```

I now get this error message:

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: 'Jan 18'

Comment: Why not handle display issues in application code?

Answer (score 0):

> I am attempting to write a query that will show monthly sales data for a selected employee and if the employee has no sales data for that month show the month and a 0.

Assuming that you have data for *some* employee in each month, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select month_year,
       sum(case when employee = 'James Jones' then total_sales else 0 end) as monthly_sales
from saleamountbyemployee sae
group by month_year;
```

Comment: Yes, at least one employee should have data in each month

Comment: How would I tie your select statement into my full query above?

Comment: @JamesFisher . . . I don't know what else your question is attempting to do, but this answers the question that you asked.  I included it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the CTE:

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@start_date, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL @number_of_months MONTH AS month_to_pull

The date format of '%Y-%m-01' doesn't match what's in the table.  If you use 'Feb 18' as the value of the @start_date parameter, it will return NULL.  The date_format you specified expects it to look like this:

SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS month_to_pull

Add ' 01' to the date, this will make it think it's the first of the month.

SELECT str_to_date(CONCAT(@start_date,' 01'), '%b %y %d') - INTERVAL @number_of_months MONTH AS month_to_pull

This will return the following if you use 'Feb 18' as the @start_date and 1 as the @number_of_months:

1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM

That VARCHAR data type and date format in the table is gonna bite you.

Comment: how would I re-write it so that data is returned?

Comment: See my edit.  I get error even when updating syntax.